# Help with Finding $\sigma$<$x$> of $ \{[0,4]\} \cup\{[\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}}): n = 0,1,2,3....\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Quick measure theory question. This is not a homework question. I just want to know if my logic is correct.

Suppose we are given a set $X = \{[0,4]\}$U$\{[\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}}): n = 0,1,2,3....\}$

And suppose we want to generate a sigma algebra $\sigma$<$x$>.

Wouldn't $\sigma$<$x$> $ = \{\emptyset, [0,4], \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^{c}\}$ because for ever n the union $\{[0,4]\}$U$\{[\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}})\}$ is just $\{[0,4]\}$?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing $[0,4] \cup [\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}})$ which is indeed equal to $[0,4]$ for all $n$ with $\{[0,4]\} \cup \{[\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}})\}$ which is equal to $\{[0,4], [\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}\frac{4}{2^{n}})\}$. The last one is a set of two subsets of reals.

Comment: So X would equal {[0,4], [2,4), [1,2), [1/2,1/40)......}?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind, I have one more question. Say we have the set X of subsets {[0,1), [1/2, 1), (1/8,1/4)} What would be the compliment of, for example (1/8, 1/4). Would it be the union of all subsets in X such that there is no overlap between that subset and (1/8, 1/4)? In this case, [1/2,1)? Im a tiny bit confused on what the complement of a subset is.

Comment: The complement is $X$ itself as none of the element of $X$ belongs to $(1/8,1/4)$.

Comment: Isn't (1/8,1/4) in x = {[0,1), [1/2,1), (1/8,1/4)}. How could the compliment of (1/8, 1/4) be x?

Comment: $X\setminus A=\{x \in X \mid x \notin A\}$. For $X= \{[0,1), [1/2,1), (1/8,1/4)\}$, none of the reals of $(1/8,1/4)$ belongs to $X$. You’re confusing $(1/8,1/4)$ with $\{(1/8,1/4)\}$. What is true is $X= \{[0,1), [1/2,1), (1/8,1/4)\} \setminus \{(1/8,1/4)\}=\{[0,1), [1/2,1)\}$